# JSON_EXTRACT() in BigQuery - Unable to pull key with \"

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I have the following JSON format. I am trying to get the value of lvl1_id key but it is giving me NULL. i guess i am not able to pick up the key correctly because of (").

I have the example JSON and SQL syntax attached for BigQuery for refrence.

NOTE: So the third column in the SQL Syntax is not giving back the correct value and is giving NULL.

```
{
    "MainKey":"703555~C55f838559g3cb5eg5d1c92283da",
    "FixedFlagKey":"true",
    "Data":{
            "rec_num":"10045_34523567778_9977234_csdn",
            "document_id":"476-CCE0C_%rfU__ss3_Adsd",
            "same_day_value":"{
                                \"lvl1_id\": \"66108271\",
                                \"account_typ\": \"22554981580\"
                                }",
            "load_date":"2024-01-01",
            "business_unit":"AXPSDB1"           
            }
}
```

--1. JSON EXTRACT syntax

```
SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT(value, '$.Data'),
  JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(value, '$.Data'),'$.same_day_value'), 
  JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(value, '$.Data'),'$.same_day_value'), '$.lvl1_id') 
FROM `tbl`
```

Comment: Can you please confirm if the json you pasted above is correct, because I getting json validation error.

Comment: Apologies, i forgot to mention That "value" is the name of the column the json is saved in in the BigQuery table. Also, since some other team is loading this file to BigQuery  we dont have a control to make any changes to json format.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is that you json is not valud.
you can use string maipulation to "convert" it, but it would be better to check where you generate the json and fix it.

Corrected, you can simplify your query

```
Set @json = '{
    "MainKey": "703555~C55f838559g3cb5eg5d1c92283da",
    "FixedFlagKey": "true",
    "Data": {
        "rec_num": "10045_34523567778_9977234_csdn",
        "document_id": "476-CCE0C_%rfU__ss3_Adsd",
        "same_day_value": {
            "lvl1_id": "66108271",
            "account_typ": "22554981580"
        },
        "load_date": "2024-01-01",
        "business_unit": "AXPSDB1"
    }
}';
```

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@json,"$.Data.same_day_value.lvl1_id")
```

| JSON_EXTRACT(@json,"$.Data.same_day_value.lvl1_id") |
| --- |
| "66108271" |